# Realm - how to find a string in a List

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Here's my object:

```
class Cat: Object {
    let toys = List<String>()
}
```

How can I find a toy in the toys array and delete it?

```
if let foundToy = cat.toys.filter(???).first {
     try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(foundToy)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are keeping an array of distinct String (i.e., the toys array doesn't contain duplicates), you can just delete the first String found:

```
if let toyIndex = cat.toys.firstIndex(of: toyNameToBeDeleted) {
     try! realm.write {
          cat.toys.remove(at: toyIndex)
     }
}
```

If you are trying to delete all String objects == to a certain toy name, do this instead:

```
 try! realm.write {
     cat.toys = cat.toys.filter { $0 != toyNameToBeDeleted }
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but "Instance method 'delete' requires that 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') inherit from 'Object'"

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Realm in a while and got my things mixed up. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @soleil It's not clear if you want to remove the object just from the cat's toy list or remove it totally from Realm but I don't think this answer will work (from realm) without the object having a primary key. The firstIndex will return the first object matching some criteria - say it's name is 'toy 0' whereas there may be other toys named 'toy 0', therefore this `cat.toys.firstIndex(of: toyToBeDeleted)` will return nil.

Comment: @Jay, it won't return nil. It will return the first String equal to toyNameToBeDeleted. It is true that I'm making the assumption that he's keeping an array of distinct String.

Comment: You would think so huh, but it's definitely returning nil here using that code. Check out the edit to my answer and see if you spot anything I am doing wrong. Also - keep in mind Realm does not support filtering on primitives in Lists so it should be a Realm object.

Comment: I don't think you can do this `cat.toys = cat.toys.filter { $0 != toyToBeDeleted }` as a List is an ObjcC Realm object (Let, not Var) and this `filter { $0 != toyNameToBeDeleted }` is a Swft LazyFilterSequence. The key there is Realm objects are lazily loaded and if you use the Swift `.filter {}` function it loads everything into memory within that list and disconnects those objects from Realm. It's similar to casting a Realm Results object to a Swift Array. If you can get that working I would LOVE to see how it's done as that would be super useful.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, which seems to work: ```if let index = cat.toys.firstIndex(where: { $0 == toyNameToBeDeleted }) {
            try! realm.write {
                cat.toys.remove(at: index)
            }
        }```

Answer (score 1):

Realm does not support queries on a List of primities (yet).

**EDIT:** Release 10.7 added support for filters/queries as well as aggregate functions on primitives so the below info is no longer completely valid. However, it's still something to be aware of.

You will need to define a Realm ToyClass and have a property of String.

See [Array of Primitives: Support queries #5361](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361)

So create a ToyClass

```
class ToyClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var toy_name = ""
}
```

and update your CatClass List

```
class CatClass: Object {
    let toys = List<ToyClass>()
}
```

There are lots of way to delete but if you know the name of the toy, you can delete it directly from Realm.

IMPORTANT - this will remove the *first* object that matches the filter criteria completely from Realm which includes the object and the reference to it in the list. Note that it's going to delete whatever object matches the first object so if you have two objects called 'toy 1' it will delete one of them - data stored in realm is 'unsorted' so the result may not be what you want.

```
if let toyToDelete = realm.objects(ToyClass.self).filter("toy_name == 'toy 1'").first {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(toyToDelete)
    }
}
```

If you just want to remove the first object that matches the criteria (which may be dangerous) from the list but keep the object in Realm, you can do this

```
let cat = realm.objects(CatClass.self).first!
if let toyToDelete = cat.toys.filter("toy_name == 'toy 1'").first {
    try! realm.write {
        cat.toys.realm?.delete(toyToDelete)
    }
}
```

You should really add a primary key to your objects so you can tell realm specifically which object to find/delete.

```
class ToyClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var toy_id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var toy_name = ""
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "toy_id"
    }
}
```

EDIT: Some testing code to demonstrate firstIndex potentially not working

Set up the cat and two toys

```
let cat0 = CatClass()
cat0.cat_name = "cat 0"

let toy0 = ToyClass()
toy0.toy_name = "toy 0"

let toy1 = ToyClass()
toy1.toy_name = "toy 1"

cat0.toys.append(toy0)
cat0.toys.append(toy1)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(cat0)
}
```

Then retrieve cat0 and attempt to get the index of toy 1

```
let cat = realm.objects(CatClass.self).filter("cat_name == 'cat 0'").first!
let toyToBeDeleted = cat.toys.filter("toy_name == 'toy 1'").first!

print(toyToBeDeleted) //prints toy 1
let index = cat.toys.firstIndex(of: toyToBeDeleted)
print(index) //prints nil
```