# Filter in realm list swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
class RetailerModel: BaseResponse {
var customFields = List<CustomFieldsModel>()
}

class CustomFieldsModel: BaseResponse {
@objc dynamic var params : ParamsModel?
}

class ParamsModel: BaseResponse {
var options = List<String>()
}
```

**I'm using realm to get data and
**RetailerModel** has an object of **CustomFieldsModel** and **CustomFieldsModel** has an object of **ParamsModel** and **ParamsModel** contains the array on which i want filter my RetailerModel data**

this is array from json that **ParamsModel** contains
"options": ["custom",
"Towers"]

what I want is just a List of all RetailerModel that have the option **"custom"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very challenging query but I think I have a solution.

First however; Primitives in Realm Lists are not well supported and are not yet queryable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518571/how-to-use-nspredicate-for-whether-a-list-of-int-contains-a-int-number/57527561#57527561) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603458/realm-how-to-find-a-string-in-a-list/62610427#62610427) for more reading.

**EDIT:** Release 10.7 added support for filters/queries as well as aggregate functions on primitives so the below info is no longer completely valid. However, it's still something to be aware of.

So we will need to add another class to hold the string data

```
class StringClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var myString = ""
}
```

so the following class will be updated to match

```
class ParamsModel: BaseResponse {
    var options = List<StringClass>()
}
```

Then to peform the query we need to leverage a Subquery due to the depth of the objects.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(customFields, $customField, ANY $customField.params.options.myString == 'custom').@count > 0")
let results = realm.objects(RetailerModel.self).filter(predicate)
```

This will return all Retailer Models whose CustomFieldsModel has a ParamsModel options List property StringClass myString property equal to 'custom'

Comment: okkk..so I have to break my Array and store its elements in StringClass then I've to make a new object of StringClass, bro this looks promising. let me try it, will get back to you.

Comment: @yawerkhan Glad I could help! A clarification is that a List object is not an Array. While they behave similarly, under the hood they are very different. List objects are Realm collections with lazily loaded objects, whereas Array's load all the objects into memory. List objects are highly efficient with large datasets - you could stuff 100,000 objects in a List and your app wouldn't break a sweat. Loading 100,000 objects in an Array on the other hand loads ALL of the objects into memory - potentially crashing an app. So when using Realm, stick with Collections when possible, like a List.